Error Code: 1364. Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value
This is the error:
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
This is my Entity class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int userId;

  
}

Table:
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_type_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7` (`email`),
  KEY `FK5snet2ikvi03wd4rabd40ckdl` (`user_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK5snet2ikvi03wd4rabd40ckdl` FOREIGN KEY (`user_type_id`) REFERENCES `users_type` (`user_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

when i make insert i get that error:
Error Code: 1364. Field 'userid' doesn't have a default value

Probably need to make userId type Integer (instead of than the primitive int), so the value can be initially be null.

Your table does not contain column userid. If the error is "doesn't have a default value" and not "unknown column" then you insert data not into users table.

There is a mismatch typing names.
in your Users entity class, the field is called userId, but in your MySQL table, the column is named user_id. To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the names used in the Java entity class match those in the database table schema.
You can fix this by modifying your entity class to include the correct column name using the @Column annotation:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "user_id") // Make sure this matches the column name in your table
 private int userId;
}


There might be several reasons for that error. Let's look more closer - the error comes from database and it is about userid field.

In the table you have user_id so it is not a table where you insert record. May be Hibernate creates another table and you miss it.
In the entity the field name is userId. How this name in camel case translates to the field name in database depends on Hibernate's settings and version. Typically it creates database fields in snake case, but you should be aware about it.
Set hibernate.show_sql: true in application.yml or hybernate.show_sql=true if you have application.properties and look what it prints

